# Main difference - sequential search algorithms

Tags: algorithm, search, sequential

**Enhanced version:**

```
A[n] <-- K
i <-- 0

while A[i] != K do
    i <-- i + 1

if i<n 
    return i
else
    return -1
```

**Normal Version**

```
i <-- 0

while i <n and A[i] != K do
    i <-- i + 1

if i<n 
    return i
else
    return -1
```

What is the main difference between enhance version and normal version ? What's point ?

Answer (score 4):

The difference is that the latter does one extra comparison (`i < n`) on each iteration.

Comment: The enhanced technique places what is known as a sentinal value (a copy of K) at the end of the target array (assumes that an extra position exists for this). The algorithm is guaranteed to terminate and find K with a single loop comparison operation. If K is found before i = N then it is in the array, otherwise not.